# What is the significance of the different avatars of Catwoman in Batman's vision during Concussion?

Tags: character, analysis, comic-adaptation, return-of-the-caped-crusaders

In [*Batman: Return of the Caped Crusaders* (2016)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5973626/), when Penguin hit Batman on his head, he sees three Catwoman instead of one in his Concussion state:

[image]

But these three Catwomen are of different hair colour and ethnicity. But why? Is it a nod to some comics book alternate Catwoman versions or a reference to the 1960's live action show?

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge.](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2833/topic-challenge-adam-west-and-his-films-completed)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know, but I suspect it is a reference to the 1960s *Batman* Series.

Catwoman was portrayed by Julie Newmar in seasons one and two and by Eartha Kitt in season three.  Also by Lee Meriwether in the *Batman* movie.

[image: Julie Newmar as Cat Woman]
Julie Newmar

[image: Eartha Kitt as Cat Woman]
Eartha Kitt

[image: Lee Meriwether as Cat Woman]
Lee Meriwether

Comment: Left one doesn't look like Lee to me, still a nice answer

Comment: The great thing about the original Batman is that the writers always had their tongue firmly planed in cheek.  This scene is hysterical for those hardcore enough to recall all 3 versions of Catwoman.